Uniqueness of units in group objects
The identity law for a group object internal to some cartesian category $C$ is given by the commutative diagram

where $G$ is some object in $C$, $e$ is a map from the terminal object $1$ to $G$, and $m$ is the multiplication map from $G\times G$ to $G$.
How can one derive from this a result analogous to the uniqueness of the identity element in groups.? I suppose one would have to use the above diagram to show that, given and $e$ and $e'$  making their respective identity law diagrams commute, morphisms $e$ and $e'$ are equal but am not sure how to proceed.

The usual proof internalises pretty straightforwardly; what are you stuck on exactly? (This works for monoid objects, not just groups.)

Basically, I was looking for something like the hint you provided. Thanks!

Hint: show that the two triangles below commute (that is, $e = m \circ \langle e, e' \rangle = e'$).


Alternatively you can argue using "functors of points," which lets you see that this sort of thing has to be true "at a glance." Namely, giving an object $G$ the structure of a group object is equivalent to upgrading its functor of points $\text{Hom}(-, G) : C^{op} \to \text{Set}$ to take values in $\text{Grp}$ instead; equivalently, a group object is a functor $C^{op} \to \text{Grp}$ whose underlying set-valued functor is representable.
(This isn't particularly important, but note that this definition of a group object does not require $C$ to be cartesian! For example you can define $C_3$ as a group object in the category of sets of size $\le 3$ this way, despite the fact that the cartesian product $C_3 \times C_3$ does not exist in this category.)
Now each of the individual groups $G(X) = \text{Hom}(X, G)$ has a unique unit. So there is a unique natural transformation $\text{Hom}(-, 1) \to \text{Hom}(-, G)$ whose value at every $X$ is this unique unit. Applying the Yoneda lemma produces a morphism $1 \to G$ which must therefore be the unique unit morphism of $G$.
Exactly the same argument also implies that the inverse morphism is unique.
